# How to convert Celcius to Farenheit, then count the number of cold and warm days, with temperatures taken from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’ve written a program to get Celsius input from the user and transfrom them to Farenheit. I’ve got most of the program down.

I just cannot figure out how to get it to output the number of occurrences for cold days and warm days, which depend on user input.

```py
# This program will convert 10 entries from Celsius to Farenheit.
print('Lets convert the temperature from the past 10 day from celsius to farenheit')

# Create the open list and loop to prompt the user for all the temperatures in Farenheit.
temps = list()
celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
while len(temps) != 10:
    temps.append(celsius)
    celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
print("Okay, the temperature, in celsius of the past 10 days has been: ", temps)

# Using a for-loop, convert each entry by the user into Celsius and print the result.
for far in range(len(temps)):
    temps[far] = (temps[far] * 1.8) + 32
print("The temperatures for everyday of the past week, converted into farenheit, is: ", temps)

def cold():
    if temps[far] < 50:
        print(len(temps[far]))
if cold:
    print(len(temps))

def warm():
    if temps[far] is (>= 50 or < 85):
        print(len(temps[far]))
if warm:
    print(len(temps))
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare functions and now you have to write logic inside, which will help you to count values of warm and cold days. Look at the code below

```
def cold(temps):
    counter = 0
    for far in range(len(temps)):
        if temps[far] < 50:
            counter += 1
    return counter

def warm(temps):
    counter = 0
    for far in range(len(temps)):
        if temps[far] >= 50 and temps[far] < 85:
            counter += 1
    return counter
    
# This program will convert 10 entries from celsius to farenheit
print('Lets convert the temperature from the past 10 day from celsius to farenheit')
# Create the open list and loop to prompt the user for all the temperatures in farenheit
temps = list()
celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
while len(temps) != 10:
    temps.append(celsius)
    celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
print ("Okay, the temperature, in celsius of the past 10 days has been: ", temps)
# Using a for loop, convert each entry by the user into celsius and print the result
for far in range(len(temps)):
    temps[far] = (temps[far] * 1.8) + 32
print ("The temperatures for everyday of the past week, converted into farenheit, is: ", temps)

print("Cold days: " + str(cold(temps)))
print("Warm days: " + str(warm(temps)))
```

**EDIT:**

Insted of using cold and warm functions you can use lamba funtion as I showed below:

```
print("Cold days: " + str(sum(value < 50 for value in temps)))
print("Warm days: " + str(sum(85 > value >= 50 for value in temps)))
```

Instead of

```
print("Cold days: " + str(cold(temps)))
print("Warm days: " + str(warm(temps)))
```

and now you can remove `cold()` and `warm()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useless line just before your while, that can be removed :

```
celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
```

Here is a version of your code that does what you want :

```
def cold(temps):
    count=0
    for temperature in temps:
        if temperature <50:count+=1
    return count

def warm(temps):
    count=0
    for temperature in temps:
        if temperature >=50 and temperature<85:count+=1
    return count     

# This program will convert 10 entries from celsius to farenheit
print('Lets convert the temperature from the past 10 day from celsius to farenheit')
print("")

# Create the open list and loop to prompt the user for all the temperatures in farenheit
temps = list()
while len(temps) != 10:
    temps.append(celsius)
    celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))

print("")    
print("Okay, the temperature, in celsius of the past 10 days has been: ", temps)
print("")

# Using a for loop, convert each entry by the user into celsius and print the result
for far in range(len(temps)):
    temps[far] = (temps[far] * 1.8) + 32

print("")    
print ("The temperatures for everyday of the past week, converted into farenheit, is: ", temps)
print("")   

print("number of cold days",cold(temps))
print("number of warm days",warm(temps))
```

Comment: it is valid to say `if [function name]`, it is treated as a boolean that is true if the function is defined, or throws a `NameError` if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

So you had multiple issues in your code:

1. You used scope variable rather the passing a variable to a fucntion.
2. You had extra `input` statmenet before the while, what caused an extra input which you didnt do anything with
3. You condition in `warm` was wrong, there is no `temps[far] is (>= 50 or < 85):`

So a working version of the code is:

```
def cold(T):
    return T < 50

def warm(T):
    return T >= 50 and T <85

# This program will convert 10 entries from celsius to farenheit
print('Lets convert the temperature from the past 10 day from celsius to farenheit')
# Create the open list and loop to prompt the user for all the temperatures in farenheit
temps = list()
while len(temps) < 10:
    celsius = int(input("Enter the temperature of everyday of the past 10 days in celsius: "))
    temps.append(celsius)
print ("Okay, the temperature, in celsius of the past 10 days has been: ", temps)
# Using a for loop, convert each entry by the user into celsius and print the result
for far in range(len(temps)):
    temps[far] = (temps[far] * 1.8) + 32
print ("The temperatures for everyday of the past week, converted into farenheit, is: ", temps)

    
cold_days = sum(list(map(cold, temps)))
warm_days = sum(list(map(warm, temps)))
print("Cold days: {:}, Warm days: {:}".format(cold_days, warm_days))
```

First, always put the function decleration on top of the main, it's good practice.

Second, `cold`/`warm` are getting a float, and are checked for a single element rather then the entire list. I think it's better in you specific case, but it depends.

Third, By using `map` and the fact that the return value is boolean (interpreted as 0/1) we can `sum` and get the desired result.

Last, please read about [`format`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp). It might be handy when you wish to print multiple stuff with variables etc.

As you might not be familiar with `map` here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) to read about it